# AWS WorkDocs SDK - How to Search a Folder?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

**Given the ID for a folder in AWS WorkDocs, how can I search that folder for a file or sub-folder that has a specific name, using the SDK? And can such a search be recursively deep vs shallow?**

Is there a better way besides fetching the metadata for all of the items and stopping once there's a match? It appears not, from this quote on [a page that provides a Python example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/business-productivity/using-the-amazon-workdocs-api-with-the-aws-sdk-for-python-and-aws-lambda/):

> Note that this code snippet searches for the file only in the current folder in the user’s MyDocs. For files in subfolders, the code needs to iterate over the subfolders by calling describe_folder_contents() on them and performing the lookup.

I see that the pricing schedule mentions search ...

> • $58/10K calls for SEARCH requests (0.0058/call)

... but *neither* the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html422000&usg=AFQjCNHck_e4K-gOX-ZUCvYefYdSl9-NsA) *nor* the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/workdocs/faq/) mentions search in the answer for "What specific actions can be taken on Amazon WorkDocs content programmatically using the Amazon WorkDocs SDK?" -- The FAQ says:

> The Amazon WorkDocs SDK allows you to perform create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) actions on WorkDocs’ users, folders, files, and permissions. You can access and modify file attributes, tag files, and manage comments associated with files.
>
> In addition to API actions, you can also subscribe to notifications that Amazon WorkDocs sends with Amazon SNS. The detailed information, including syntax, responses and data types for the above actions, is available in the WorkDocs API Reference Documentation.

The [labelling API](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-workdocs-administrative-sdk-adds-apis-to-access-and-update-metadata-tags-and-comments/) might be the answer...

> The labelling API allows you to tag files and folders so that you can better organize them, and to use tags when searching for files programmatically.

... but I'm having trouble finding an example, or even which classes comprise the "labelling API". Are they referring to [Package software.amazon.awssdk.services.resourcegroupstaggingapi](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi/package-summary.html) ?

Description
Resource Groups Tagging API

> A tag is a label that you assign to an AWS resource. A tag consists of
> a key and a value, both of which you define. For example, if you have
> two Amazon EC2 instances, you might assign both a tag key of "Stack."
> But the value of "Stack" might be "Testing" for one and "Production"
> for the other.
>
> Tagging can help you organize your resources and enables you to
> simplify resource management, access management and cost allocation.
>
> You can use the resource groups tagging API operations to complete the
> following tasks:
>
> 1. Tag and untag **supported** resources located in the specified Region for
>    the AWS account.
> 2. Use tag-based filters to **search** for resources located in the specified
>    Region for the AWS account.
> 3. List all existing tag keys in the specified Region for the AWS
>    account.
> 4. List all existing values for the specified key in the specified Region
>    for the AWS account.

In the list of supported resources on that page, it lists S3 (buckets only) and WorkSpaces, but there's no mention of WorkDocs. Is this what I'm looking for?